# ShareKit SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL

Tags: ios, facebook, url, c-preprocessor, sharekit

I'm implementing **ShareKit** in my app. In the **SHKConfig.h** file, in the section where the Facebook data is inserted, there is a line saying: **#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL @""**.

What am I supposed to enter there?

Comment: looks like you found an answer, if so plz can you share because i have the same dillema and i dont know what to do

Comment: Hi khizar, I did find an answer to that - look in my other questions. I have at least 10 regarding to ShareKit and I managed to clean all the errors and warnings - sometimes, I had to re-phrase my question several times until I got an answer, sometimes I had to put "Bounty" on it so someone will take a look at it, and sometimes I found it myself and published the answer under my question. If you couldn't find what you were looking for in any of my other questions+answers let me know and I will try my best to help.

Comment: well at first i did not find an answer so i decided to test it leaving this field empty and it worked. so i did not look any further. So thanks for the reply :)

on a seperate note, and i know i should make another question for this, but i have come across a problem with email. there is no error, looks like its working as it should but i do not get the email.any idea what might be the problem? Or where can i find an answer because after looking for an hour , i still dont know whats the problem.

Comment: I have no idea, i.e., I didn't encounter this myself. Intuitively several questions come to my mind - have you touched any of the inner files? does it work when you run ShareKit Example App (the one you get when you download ShareKit files)? Can you send emails from other apps that have an email feature? 
If it's not one of these silly things that happen once in a while, maybe you can show me how you call ShareKit from your app - maybe I can look it up and see if I can see something funny in the code

Comment: thanx for being so helpful. I have made a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905081/email-not-working-in-sharekit-and-no-errors] .and there is a little more detail there. see if you can help. thanx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Leave it empty

```
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""
```